# How do I shorten this image loading process?

Tags: javascript, image, load

This code loads images for a javascript application:

```
var sampleImage = new Image();
sampleImage.ready = false;
sampleImage.onload = setAssetReady;
sampleImage.src = IMAGE_FILE;

function setAssetReady(){
this.ready = true;
}
```

I'd like to figure out a way to not use four lines of code for every image being used.

I used this way suggested by the answer (Unless I'm doing it wrong):

```
var sampleImage = new Image();
sampleImage = loadTheImage(imageFile);

function loadTheImage(imageFile){
this.ready = false;
this.onload = setAssetReady;
this.src = imageFile;
}

function setAssetReady(){
this.ready = true;
}
```

The images did not load successfully and when sampleImage.ready was evaluated in an if statement in a different place in the code, an error message was returned that said:

Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined

And again, I'm doing this process for many images, so I only want one or two lines of code to write for each instead of the four I originally had. Or if there is any other process you suggest.

Comment: Use a loop to create your image HTML fragments.

Comment: I used the first process suggested and ran into difficulties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function loadTheImage(imageFile){
    sampleImage.ready = false;
    sampleImage.onload = setAssetReady;
    sampleImage.src = imageFile;
};
function setAssetReady(){
    this.ready = true;
};
```

And then just call `loadTheImage` for every image.

Comment: I misread the question. I thought he just wanted to avoid 4 lines of code, missed the `for every image being used` part. I used jQuery to extendo the `Image()` object: `$.extend(new Image(), {ready: false, onload: setAssetReady, src: 'IMAGE_FILE'});`. Kinda not needed I guess.